# change file from gbk into utf-8 and display it in console

Tags: python

My system is :python3.3+win7.
The file `c:\\test_before` is encode in gbk.you can download it and 
save it as `c:\\test_before` from here to test.
http://pan.baidu.com/s/1i3DSuKd
I can get every line output when i set `chcp 936` .

```
cname="c:\\test_before"
dat=open(cname,"r")
for line in dat.readlines():
    print(line)
```

[image]

Now ,i change the file into utf-8  with python.

```
cname="c:\\test_before"
dat=open(cname,"rb")
new=open("c:\\test_utf-8","wb")
for line in dat.readlines():
    line=line.decode("gbk").encode("utf-8")
    new.write(line)

new.close()
```

when i set `chcp 65001`,and run it

```
new=open("c:\\test_utf-8","r")
for line in new.readlines():
    print(line)
```

why i got wrong output?
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xa5 in position 370: illegal
multibyte sequence.

Comment: Which python version (2 or 3)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite possible that Python does not detect the temporary codepage changes done with the `chcp` command, so it would not use the correct encoding when you call `open`.  You can quite possibly verify that yourself by doing this:

```
>>> fd = open('/tmp/somefile.txt', 'r')
>>> fd
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/tmp/somefile.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

You can of course override this in Python 3, you can do something like:

```
>>> fd = open('/tmp/somefile.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8')
>>> fd
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/tmp/somefile.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

Making the `encoding` parameter more explicit is probably what you want.

Also, you can also open the write side without using the binary mode (I saw you specifying `'wb'`.  Just use `'w'` and be explicit about your target encoding if you are translating the encodings.

```
>>> fd2 = open('/tmp/write.txt', 'w', encoding='UTF-8')
>>> fd2.write(u'abcd話')
5
```

It returns number of characters written, however.

To complete your translation, you can definitely do something like

```
cname = "c:\\test_before"
dat = open(cname, "r", encoding="gbk")
new = open("c:\\test_utf-8", "w", encoding="utf-8")
for line in dat.readlines():
    new.write(line)

new.close()
```

Finally, you should use the file handler context manager for consistency and saving you from needing to close files in this trivial use case, your code would look something like this:

```
def gbk_to_utf8(source, target):
    with open(source, "r", encoding="gbk") as src: 
        with open(target, "w", encoding="utf-8") as dst: 
            for line in src.readlines():
                dst.write(line)
```